# Scroll on div that fills rest of the space from parent element

Tags: html, css

**THE ISSUE**

I've got the site with sidebar that have fixed position and is always 100% height. The issue is that in sidebar I've got few static elements and one div with dynamic content that's suppose to fill the rest of the space of the sidebar.

**THE CODE**

```html
<div id="sidebar" style="height:100%; background:#73A2; postion:fixed; flex:none; overflow-y:hidden;">
  <button>one</button><br/>
  <button>two</button><br/>
  <button>three</button><br/> //more static content

  <div id="scrollableDiv" style="overflow-y:auto; height:100%;">
    Really long content
  </div>

</div>
```

**THE RESULT**

What I've managed to get is almost final effect because the scrollable div is filling rest of the space but looks like it takes full parent height for setting it's scroll height. The effect is that around 10% of scroll is overflowing under the screen when i scroll to see the last position from the dynamic list. Any idea how to handle that without calculating the height of static elements? When scrollableDiv's height is set for eg. to 80%, it's not filling rest of the space (around 10px left) but scroll is working perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need to change to make it work for this demonstration:

- You need to use `display:flex` on the **sidebar** and `flex-direction:column` with a **fixed width** *(added **top:0, left:0** as well to dismiss any additional margins)* to make it flexible (*but for only dynamic long content*).
- Set the dynamic long content **flex:1;** with **overflow-y auto**, this way it will always *be flexible and never overflow*.

***Note:*** The red background is to show that it is taking the full remaining space of the sidebar.

**When there is a really long overflowing content:**

```css
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  background: #73A2;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  flex: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:200px;
}

#scrollableDiv {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <button>one</button><br/>
  <button>two</button><br/>
  <button>three</button><br/> //more static content

  <div id="scrollableDiv">
    Really long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentv
  </div>

</div>
```

**When there isn't overflowing content:**

```css
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  background: #73A2;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  flex: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:200px;
}

#scrollableDiv {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <button>one</button><br/>
  <button>two</button><br/>
  <button>three</button><br/> //more static content

  <div id="scrollableDiv">
     contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long contentReally long content
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @susanoo No problem :)